# Can't even install 20.04 (black screen)

Tags: boot, drivers

I just got a new Radeon RX 6700XT. Turns out, when attempting to install 20.04 from scratch, the common install menu does not even load: after DVD install media check for errors, screen goes black.

I've noticed that even the "media check for errors" screen is different than usual (had installed 20.04 previously on this PC with old GPU), like super basic text graphics.

What might be the problem? Can it be that 20.04 installer does not have basic drivers for the 6700XT so it does not even display the install menu?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be right here. The drivers for the latest 6000 series Radeon cards might not yet be fully *out of the woods* for Linux yet, and of course if your previous install with an older GPU worked, this further provides good foundation to say it might be that the drivers are just not capable yet.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Yes, looks like it is a driver compatibility issue. Let's see if next LTS version solves the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is the next LTS version to release, and will not be available for another year. Your best bet is to keep an eye out for a driver that is released for that line of GPUs on Linux; or better yet, you can try and make your own one :P - all the best.